# EkEvent is showing on each day

Tags: iphone, ekevent

I am using this code to add an event to a device however on calender in device its getting shown on each date upto the end date of the event

```
NSString *GoalDate =  [[[DFDateFormatterFactory sharedFactory] 
dateFormatterWithFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd" andLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]

stringFromDate:self.datepicker.date];

        [AppHelper saveToUserDefaults:GoalDate withKey:@"goalsdates"];

        NSInteger dummyInteger = [[AppHelper userDefaultsForKey:@"event"]intValue];

        if(dummyInteger!=0)
        {

        [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
         {
        if (!granted)
        { return;
        }
    EKRecurrenceEnd *endRecurrence = nil;

   endRecurrence = [EKRecurrenceEnd recurrenceEndWithEndDate:self.datepicker.date];

   EKRecurrenceRule *recurrence;

 if(dummyInteger==1)
 {
 recurrence= [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] initRecurrenceWithFrequency: EKRecurrenceFrequencyDaily
 interval:1 daysOfTheWeek:nil daysOfTheMonth:nil  monthsOfTheYear:nil   weeksOfTheYear:nil  daysOfTheYear:nil setPositions:nil  end:endRecurrence];

 }

    if(dummyInteger==2)
    {

    recurrence = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] initRecurrenceWithFrequency: EKRecurrenceFrequencyWeekly  interval:7 daysOfTheWeek:nil daysOfTheMonth:nil  monthsOfTheYear:nil   weeksOfTheYear:nil  daysOfTheYear:nil setPositions:nil  
end:endRecurrence];

    }


             if(dummyInteger==3)
             {

recurrence = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] initRecurrenceWithFrequency: EKRecurrenceFrequencyWeekly interval:1 daysOfTheWeek:nil daysOfTheMonth:nil  monthsOfTheYear:nil   weeksOfTheYear:nil  daysOfTheYear:nil setPositions:nil  end:endRecurrence];

            }

             if(dummyInteger==4)
             {


 recurrence = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] initRecurrenceWithFrequency: EKRecurrenceFrequencyYearly  interval:1 daysOfTheWeek:nil daysOfTheMonth:nil  monthsOfTheYear:nil   weeksOfTheYear:nil  daysOfTheYear:nil setPositions:nil  end:endRecurrence];
                              }



        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];

        event.title = [AppHelper userDefaultsForKey:@"nameofagoal"];

             event.allDay = false;

             event.startDate =[NSDate date];

     //  event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*7];  //set 1 hour meeting

             event.endDate =  self.datepicker.date;




       // event.endDate = endDate;
        [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

        NSError *err = nil;

        [event addRecurrenceRule: recurrence];      

        [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];

        savedEventId = event.eventIdentifier;  //this is so you can access this event later
    }];
```

Comment: Hi karthika, Do you know regarding this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

By default event kit adds event from start to end date. If your start and end date are different. Then it will show on all the days from start to end. If you want to show event only on start day and end day of event then you must have to add two events with same name but different ending dates.

You can also set `allDay` property of the event to YES. In this case event will not cover the whole screen if you are on the day view of calendar.